# Why is it that my 2014 MacBook pro faster than my 2017 iMac

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, performance

My MacBook is old and overheats a lot, and my iMac is new, has 4k resolution, a quad core CPU, but it's slow.

The main difference is that my new iMac has a 1TB HDD, and my old MacBook has a 128GB SSD.

Why is the older computer faster than the new one?
What can I do to speed it up?

Comment: you already answered your own question: SSD make things faster than HD!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. This would be a great thing to ask someone you are sitting with and you can talk back and forth 20 questions to determine what precisely you consider fast. Can you review [tour] and [ask] so that you can edit this with details that will help us help you? If you don’t know how to measure disk speed, that would make a great edit. I suspect the disk - how can I measure that? If you show a specific task to measure - we can help with faster for that task.

Comment: Overheats?  Are fans still clean or does dust obstruct the airflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much any SSD is going to be much faster than an HDD.

You're looking at much faster read speeds on an SSD.

A typical 7200 RPM HDD will deliver a read/write speed of 80-160MB/s. On the other hand, a typical SSD will deliver read/write speed of between 200 MB/s to 550 MB/s.
[Source](https://tekhattan.com/blog/hardware/ssd-vs-hdd-speed-lifespan-and-reliability/)

But, fret not! You *can* add an SSD to your iMac.
Here's a link from the Apple's website. [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8256573). I'm sure you can find a DIY guide there somewhere. Or check with your local Apple Authorized Service Provider.

But answering your question, if your 2014 has an SSD and your 2017 has a HDD, the one with the SSD is going to be faster, regardless of the year.